# How many unique Taproot addresses (eg pubkeys) are possible?

Tags: address-generation, taproot, bech32-address

Given that Taproot (SegWit v1) addresses are basically equivalent to a public key -- does that mean that there are a full 2<sup>256</sup> possibilities?  Or is the overall number of possible addresses reduced in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taproot outputs contain *x-only* (tweaked) public keys. Due to the lack of Y coordinates, the number of valid keys is halved.

The exact number of possible x-only keys is *2<sup>255</sup> - 216210193282829828426210433197484072800*.

Comment: The other half can still be made into valid SegWit v1 outputs (and therefore addresses), even though they would not be spendable, right?

Comment: That's right. The address format can encode X coordinates that don't have corresponding public keys, but any coins sent to such an output are irrevocably lost.